# NotSupportedException for form controls after receiving data with serial port

Tags: c#, multithreading, serial-port, controls, windows-ce

I am developing a program for Windows CE with visual studio 2008 . I am using Serialport data_received event to get data but after receiving data(string) when I want to set it to Textbox or Label 's Text property a NotSupportedException from TextBox.Text is throwing.
Instead, if I set a local variable with received data ,It works without any problem.

Exception :

An unhandled exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

I hardly remember that years ago when I worked with sockets I had such problem which was related to threads !

can any one Help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're having is most likely that you cannot access user interface elements from any thread other than the main thread.

what you need to do is invoke code in the main thread to actually do the work of setting the properties you need.

this is done by declaring a delegate sub and passing it into control.invoke

see the following:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172879.aspx

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a1hetckb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)